# Amplitude and resonance for a forced mass-spring system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to grade a differential equations quiz about forced oscillations. Because I remember very little from my differential equations course, I'm going to appeal to MSE. The question is as follows:

> For a forced mass-spring system with equation $mx'' + bx' + kx = F\cos{\omega t}$, investigate the possibility of practical resonance of this system. Find the amplitude $C(\omega)$ of steady periodic forced oscillations with frequency $\omega$. Sketch the graph $C(\omega)$ and find the practical resonance frequency (if any). $m=1, b=6,k=45, F=50$.

Here is my interpretation of what is happening:

First, we have to realize that the amplitude $C(\omega)$ is given by $$C(\omega)=\frac{F}{\sqrt{(k-m\omega^2)^2+(b\omega)^2}}$$

Then we see if $C(\omega)$ is maximized anywhere in the positive reals by setting $C'(\omega)=0$ and solving. After doing so, we get solutions $\omega=0,\pm\sqrt{27}$. Since it only makes sense to analyze positive frequencies, we have that $\omega=\sqrt{27}$. This is called our practical resonance frequency $(\omega^*)$.

Here's where I start to get a bit fuzzy (Let me know if the following is wrong):

We say that the system is $\underline{\text{resonating}}$ if $\omega^*\approx\omega_0$, where $\omega_0 = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$. Since $\omega_0 = \sqrt{45}$ in this problem, and $\sqrt{45}$ is not that close to $\omega^*=\sqrt{27}$, we conclude that the system is not resonating.

Does this idea sound right? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plot the response you get the graph below.  Alpha agrees the maximum is at $\omega=\sqrt{27}$.  The fact that the maximum response is higher than the response at zero frequency indicates that it is underdamped and resonating.  I wouldn't look at how the damped and undamped frequencies relate, rather whether the response peaks. This is a rather weak resonance as shown by the low ratio of maximum response to response at zero frequency (about $1.3$) and by the width of the peak.
[image]

Comment: Small point: the $6x^2$ in your plot should be $(6x)^2$, which I believe will change the maximum to $\sqrt{27}$. But even still, what about this graph tells us that the system will be resonating? Just the fact that it's not monotone decreasing?

Comment: You are correct and the maximum does change to $\sqrt {27}$ as you say.  I have updated the plot.  The resonance is also not nearly as strong, but it is still there.